# the limit of a probability density function

Tags: probability, statistics

I have one maths challenge which I could not resolve. The question is the following. Let f(x) denotes the probability density of a continuous RV., X. I want to know the **limit f(x)** as x approaches to either -∞ or +∞. It might seem silly, but I have do idea how to do that.

Comment: You don't you know how to prove it or don't even have idea of the answer?

Comment: @leonbloy I have no idea of the answer. I am less technical guy. There maybe a proof for a specific type of density, but I have no idea how it can be done for a generalized PDF.

Comment: It may have no limit, for example $f(x)=\sum_{j\geq 1} 2^{-j}\chi_{(2n,2n+1)}$.

Comment: The limit depends on the $f(x)$. Write down it, please.

Comment: @Riccardo.Alestra; you may suggest me a few examples of some known f(x).

Comment: Here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_probability_distributions, you can find a list of pdf and choose one of them.

Comment: @Riccardo.Alestra: I would like to know the case of a generalised distribution. But if that isn't possible, I will go for the normal, exponential and log-normal distributions

Answer (score 5):

It is not necessary that a density have any limit as $x\to\infty$ or $x\to -\infty$.  The sole criteria for a function $f$ to be a density are $f\ge 0$ a.e. and that
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\mbox{d}x = 1.$$

Such a function could have high, narrow spikes at either or both ends.  It is, in fact, possible to have
$$\limsup_{n\to\infty} f(x) = \infty$$ and 
$$\limsup_{n\to-\infty} f(x) = \infty.$$
Try to construct such an example. It is not terribly hard.

Comment: what about the continuity of $f$?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that this question arose in an undergraduate (non-measure-theoretic)
course in probability, the answer that the OP (or perhaps the OP's instructor) 
might have been looking for 
might be that 
$$\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x) = \lim_{x\to -\infty} f(x) = 0.$$
The rationale would be that if $f(x)$ were converging to a positive number $c$
as $x \to \infty$, then
$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)\,\mathrm dx$ would diverge. In more detail
for the OP's benefit, there would exist an $x_0$ such that for all $x > x_0$,
$|f(x) - c| < \frac{c}{2} \Rightarrow f(x) > \frac{c}{2}$, and so
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)\,\mathrm dx 
\geq \int_{x_0}^{\infty}f(x)\,\mathrm dx
\geq \int_{x_0}^{\infty}\frac{c}{2}\,\mathrm dx.$$
Indeed, not only must $f(x)$ converge to $0$ as $x \to \pm\infty$
but the convergence
must be faster than $|x|^{-1}$.

Of course, since $f(x)$ can be viewed as a representative member of a
class of density functions that differ only on a set of measure zero,
one can find other functions in this class for which 
$\limsup f(x) = \infty$, e.g.
$$fx) = \begin{cases}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left(-\frac{x^2}{2}\right),
&x ~\text{is irrational},\\
|x|, &x ~\text{is rational.}
\end{cases}$$